# how to pass string in onclick function html

Tags: javascript, html

I tried with old question, there they passing the value in js to js.But I would like to pass string from html to javascript. but it gives

> Uncaught reference error

my `html` is

```
<a href="#" onclick="test(TEST123)">
```

and my `javascript` is,

```
function test(p){
   alert(p)
}
```

how can I pass the string>

Comment: `<a href="#" onclick="test('TEST123')">` or JS parser will look for variable having name as `TEST123`

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="test('TEST123')">

Comment: `<a href="#" onclick="test('TEST123')">`

Comment: I agree with @LearningMode and am upvoting his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="test('TEST123')">
```

just wite string parameter in your js function

Answer (score 4):

If you write `test(TEST123)` then it looks for the variable with `TEST123` name.
 so you have to pass it as a string not as a variable

```js
function test(p){
   alert(p)
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="test('TEST123')"> and
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using select tag, and want to pass the value on selecting the option item, then you can use

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="checkifclick('hello')" name="product_name">
```

and in javascript,

```
<script>
    function checkifclick(test) {
        alert(test);
    }
```

Basically, i had faced this problem once, i wanted to call the function and wanted to pass the variables into that javascript function.

`class="form-control"` is using to beautify the element, `form-control` is a build-in class of bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.