# Passing an input parameter in JS showing Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to pull a string variable into my javascript function from a PHP file and am being returned: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`.

I have tried to use `onclick="showContent('home')"` but this does not load the page at all. I assumed that placing home in parentheses would act as a string parameter and fill that variable in the javascript function.

In my header.php:
`echo "<img src='../images/home.png' onclick='showContent('home')' alt='Home' /></a>";`

In my menu.js:

`function showContent(showThis){
    alert(showThis);
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: Double-check where you have `$home` defined, it's not able to use the variable.

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with PHP now?

Comment: @PatrickQ No, it still does. The header.php file is where the html is being generated from.

Comment: That doesn't matter, your question has no PHP code in it.

Comment: New possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792954/how-to-pass-string-in-onclick-function-html

Comment: @PatrickQ Fixed question.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
echo "<img src='../images/home.png' onclick='showContent(\"$home\")' alt='Home' />";
```

Comment: This shows up as empty. And when I click view source code it appears like this in the final HTML: `onclick='showContent("")'`

Comment: @FrankDoe Then `$home` is empty.  You should include (in your question) the code that is supposed to be assigning a value to `$home`

Comment: Updated my question. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You are not interpolating the variable `$home` correctly into the JS.

```
echo "<img src=\"../images/home.png\" onclick=\"showContent('{$home}')\" alt=\"Home\" />";
```